# the best way to make a table with commands that run at a certain time - cronjob is the best way?

Tags: php, mysql, cron

FIrst of all some introduction - my servers are linux and my database is mysql.

I'm looking for the best way to make a a table with commands that run at a certain time.

For example lets say i want to search every day at 12:00 in the database for some data and send it by e-mail.

So i've heard about cronjob but i'm not sure if that's the best way to approach this task.

Does anyone done something similar and can give me an advise about the best way to do so?